# Why is the start row of \rowcolors ignored in tabularx?

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, rowcolor

Seems like `\rowcolors` when used for a `{tabularx}` doesn’t work properly: The specific number of the first row to be colored is ignored. This is not the case for a normal `{tabular}`.

[image]

In both tables the coloring should start in the third row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{tabularx}| \\[2ex]
   \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \begin{tabularx}{40mm}{X}
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{tabular}| \\[2ex]
   \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \begin{tabular}{p{40mm}}
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in `xcolor`/`tabularx`?

---

This question is kind of a follow-up question of my answer on [Table cell with unwanted black background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297335/4918)

Comment: In case of `tabularx` it is a political act: an Ukrainian flag is added if first two rows. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously `tabularx` doesn't have bugs, this is a documented feature.

[image]

`TX` sets the table several times, and restores latex counters but tex primitive counters can not be restored so easily. This defines a latex counter to shadow the `\newcount` allocated counter defined by `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcounter{tblerows}
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{tabularx}| \\[2ex]
   \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \begin{tabularx}{40mm}{X}
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{tabular}| \\[2ex]
   \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \begin{tabular}{p{40mm}}
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what do you mean by “documented”? Niether a search for `rowcolor` nor `color` (or `color`) shows result in the manual (that’s what I checkt before asking this question …). And how can you beside there are no bug (just asking for curiosity …)

Comment: @Tobi mostly it was a joke, it's my code so clearly I believe it's bug free. Actually the fact that plain tex counters are not restored isn't as documented as i remembered. it is documented that latex counters _are_ restored. tabularx was written long before rowcolor (or even color package) existed so you wouldn't see anything specifically about that, although it's not really related to color just that the counter increases by 1 every row but is not reset so by  the final setting it is already much bigger than 3 before the table starts.

Comment: I see :-) I wonder if the should be a “fix” for this non-bug in either of the packages since both are quite popular …

Comment: @David Carlisle Well this comment is not directly related to the question but rather to the code you have written. Why `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` were not used when you defined the commands `\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum` as `@` can be seen in that line? Are there special cases where `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`  are not necessary?

Comment: @hesham I just used csname there as an alternative I could have used `\makeatletter` then used `\c@tblerows` as if @ is a letter that parses as a singe csname, but if `@` is a non-letter then `  `\c@tblerows` parses as `\c @tblerows` so would put a cedilla accent on an `@`...  but you can still construct the token via `\csname` even with non-letters.

Comment: That was quite informative to my little knowledge. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

For information, with `{NiceTabular}` and `{NiceTabularX}` of `nicematrix` (and its built-in command `\rowcolors` available in the `\CodeBefore`), you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{NiceTabularX}| \\[2ex]
   \begin{NiceTabularX}{40mm}{X}
   \CodeBefore
      \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \Body
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
   \verb|{NiceTabular}| \\[2ex]
   \begin{NiceTabular}{p{40mm}}
   \CodeBefore
      \rowcolors{3}{blue!50}{yellow!60}
   \Body
      1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]