# How to create more space between table and the text?

Tags: tables, center

I am trying to create more space between the words and my table. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,noindentafter,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{colortbl} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen mit cellcolor


\title{h}
\author{gh}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}
In der Tabelle \ref{tab:x:Komplexität} ist die Komplexität der einzelnen Frequenzschätzungsverfahren aufgelistet.
\begin{table}[ht!]
   \begin{center}
   \centering
   \caption{Komplexität der Frequensschätzungsverfahren}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
   \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
       \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
       \hline
       Verfahren & \textbf{FFT}  & \textbf{STFT} &  \textbf{Pspectrum} & \textbf{Welch}\\
       \hline
       Komp & $O(N\cdot log(N))$ & $O(\Delta t\cdot N\cdot log(N))$& - & $O(N\cdot log(L))$ \\
       \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
       \hline
       Verfahren & \textbf{Periodogram} & \textbf{Lomb-Scargle} & \textbf{Kreuzkorrelation} & \textbf{Zero-Crossing} \\
       \hline
       Komp & $O(N\cdot log(N))$ & $O(N\textsuperscript{2})$ & $O(N\cdot N\textsubscript{S})$ & -\\
       \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
       \hline
       Verfahren & \textbf{Burg-Methode} & \textbf{Yule-Walker} & \textbf{MUSIC} & \textbf{Eigenvektor} \\
       \hline
       Komp &$O(N\cdot log(N) + p\textsuperscript{2})$& $O(p\textsuperscript{2}+N\cdot p)$ & $O(N\textsubscript{Kor}\textsuperscript{3})$ & $O(N\textsubscript{Kor}\textsuperscript{3})$ \\
       \hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{center}
   \label{tab:x:Komplexität}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{table}
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{rclcrcl}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  $N$ & = & Signallänge &$\qquad$& $\Delta t$ &=& Zeitfenster \\
  $L$ & = & Länge der Überlappung  &        &  $N\textsubscript{S}$  &=& Verzögerungslänge\\
  $p$ & = & Ordnung &$\qquad$& Komp & = & Komplexität\\
  $N\textsubscript{kor}$ & = & gewählte Länge der Korrelationsmatrix\\
\end{tabular}\end{center}
afhkf

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Put the label just after the captions. And  don't use the `center` environment within `table`: you'll have a spurious vertical spacing – `\centering` is enough.

Comment: Thank you! @Bernard Do you know how to create more space between the text and table I marked with green?

Comment: You could add a \\ over your `afhkf` to create an empty line.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible @TornaxO7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Your table is wider than default `article` text width. So I add in preamble `\usepackage{geometry}`. For table I suggest to use `tabularx` and  for legend below table `align` defined in `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks,noindentafter,nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Für farbige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcounter{tblerows}% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297345/
                     % why-is-the-start-row-of-rowcolors-ignored-in-tabularx
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{h}
\author{gh}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}
In der Tabelle \ref{tab:x:Komplexität} ist die Komplexität der einzelnen Frequenzschätzungsverfahren aufgelistet.
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
\caption{Komplexität der Frequensschätzungsverfahren}
\label{tab:x:Komplexität}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*{4}{C|} } % <---
    \hline
Verfahren & \textbf{FFT}  & \textbf{STFT} &  \textbf{Pspectrum} & \textbf{Welch}\\
   \hline
   Komp & $O(N{\cdot}log(N))$ & $O(\Delta t{\cdot}N{\cdot}log(N))$& -- & $O(N{\cdot}log(L))$ \\
   \hline
   Verfahren & \textbf{Periodogram} & \textbf{Lomb-Scargle} & \textbf{Kreuzkorrelation} & \textbf{Zero-Crossing} \\
   \hline
   Komp & $O\bigl(N{\cdot}log(N)\bigr)$ & $O(N^2)$ & $O(N{\cdot}N_{\text{S}})$ & -\\
   \hline
   Verfahren & \textbf{Burg-Methode} & \textbf{Yule-Walker} & \textbf{MUSIC} & \textbf{Eigenvektor} \\
   \hline
   Komp &$O(N{\cdot}log(N) + p^2)$& $O(p^{2}+N{\cdot}p)$ & $O(N_{\text{Kor}}^{3})$ & $O(N_{\text{Kor}}^{3})$ \\
   \hline
   \end{tabularx}

    \begin{align*}
N   & = \text{Signallänge}    
        &   \Delta t    & = \text{Zeitfenster}          \\
L   & = \text{Länge der Überlappung}  
        &   N_{\text{S}}& = \text{Verzögerungslänge}    \\
p   & = \text{Ordnung} 
        & \text{Komp}   & =  \text{Komplexität}         \\
N_{\text{kor}}
    & = \text{gewählte Länge der Korrelationsmatrix}    
        &               &  
    \end{align*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[11]

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

**Edit (1):** added is vertical line at left side of the table and improved table code.

**Edit (2):**  improved table coloring.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how to add a vertical line as I marked above? @Zarko

Comment: @Adam, I wonder, why you not ad it :-). just add vertical baron beginning of columns specification. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!