# How to link the bibliography correctly?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, hyperlink

I have written a Latex document. However, the bibliography, table of contents, and list of tables are not linked correctly. Does someone know, how to fix this?

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{colortbl} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen mit cellcolor
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcounter{tblerows}% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297345/
                     % why-is-the-start-row-of-rowcolors-ignored-in-tabularx
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{footnote}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}         
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Erzeugen von Blindtext
\usepackage{booktabs}               % huebsche Tabellen
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % Farben
\usepackage{booktabs}               % hübsche Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{selinput}               % Eingabecodierung automatisch ermitteln …
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}
\newcommand*{\EigeneAbbildung}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Eigene Abbildung~#1}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\rightmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{sfsb}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what `not linked correctly` entails. Linked to what?